# How may I more easily change the fontFace in Windows Terminal?

Tags: windows-10, fonts, windows-terminal, font-faces

I've installed a few console fonts from Github for Windows Terminal, but when I go to Settings to select them I get dialog to wit that 'the selected font is not found' and am advised to install the 'missing' font or choose another one. I double-checked. My fonts are installed. What gives?

Answer (score 0):

Entering Windows Terminal **"Settings"** (CTRL,) and there selecting my **"Profile"** of choice which is currently "PowerShell 7 Preview" from the navigation drawer (top-left hamburger menu), I then select **"Appearance"** from the available tabs. There the **"Font face"** field will require a font family name to be entered.

**Crucial Caveat:** As the font family name may not be immediately apparent, it may be derived from the related fonts installed as it is the named portion that is common to all the installed fonts from that particular family. For example, "VictorMono" includes several typefaces and was the common camel-cased portion to the newly installed fonts on my machine. To derive the required "Font face" font-family name I simply **removed the camel-casing inserting a required space** as such, "Victor Mono". This resolved the "Unable to find the selected font "VictorMono"' warning dialog I'd been getting supplying the camel-casing that was otherwise evident in all the named fonts I installed. Setting the correct font family name, I was then able to **select the preferred typeface** from the drop-down field **"Font weight"**. (Please refer to the attached image.) Windows Terminal was not complaining about missing fonts after this.

Please note:
This question is admittedly related to a stackoverflow page that ambiguously supplies the answer but neglectfully fails to clarify the apparent naming convention used to arrive at the solution. This answer, I believe, makes it explicit in order to save others time and potential frustration from the task of otherwise having to carefully (hopefully) discern it. Here is the stackoverflow page I refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62462220/cant-change-fontface-in-windows-terminal

Thank you.

[image: Windows Terminal Settings to select installed font family]